# How to add extra portion beyond Bootstrap Grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a Photoshop layout designed as per the Bootstrap's 12 Grid system, where there is an extra portion which is exceeding the grids, I'm not sure how to add that. I've tried to add that portion using :after selector. Is there any alternative?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the layout:]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using `:after` selector and defining the behaviors by using CSS3 @media Query.

Here is my codes:

```
.form-container {
    position: relative;
}

.form-container:after {
    content: "";
    height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -202px;
    top: 0px;
    border-right: 202px solid #764B3A;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .form-container:after {
        border-right: none;
    }
}
```